# inserting integer at each index of python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I insert integer '5' at each index of following list an element in new list per index

I have a list

```
['2', '6', '8']
```

and would like to insert '5' in following way:

```
['5', '2', '6', '8']
['2', '5', '6', '8']
['2', '6', '5', '8']
['2', '6', '8', '5']
```

Comment: The integer `5` or the string `'5'`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl oh ok removing dupe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension using slices of the list to and from each index:

```
>>> lst = ['2', '6', '8']
>>> [lst[:i] + ["5"] + lst[i:] for i in range(len(lst)+1)]
[['5', '2', '6', '8'],
 ['2', '5', '6', '8'],
 ['2', '6', '5', '8'],
 ['2', '6', '8', '5']]
```

Or using `*`-unpacking, same result: `[[*lst[:i], "5", *lst[i:]] for ...]`. Both versions create a bunch of temporary list slices. The alternative would be to use a loop, make a copy of the list, and then calling `insert`; both approaches should have ~O(2n) per list, so it does not really make a difference.